# Server sent event EventStream does not trigger "onmessage" but Chrome Debug shows data in "EventStream" tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-stream

I'm using SSE with the EventStream built in logic for javascript. While having `onopen` return a successful result the `onmessage` callback is not working.
Odd thing here is that within Chrome in the **EventStream** tab the data results are listed as I expect them.

**This is my JS snippet for the EventSource**

```
var eventSource;
  $(function () {
    eventSource  = new EventSource('get/status/');

    eventSource.onopen = function () {
      console.log("Sse connection opened");
    };

    eventSource.onerror = function () {
      console.log("error occured");
    };

    eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log("received");
    };

  });
```

[image]

As you can see there is data being emitted but `onmessage` is never triggered. Can anybody explain this behaviour to me?

**EDIT**: `onopen` and `onerror` do both work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to the screenshot, your event-stream contains events of type `"foo"`, not `"message"`. That is only the default type (absent an `event` field in the event-stream). From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#processField):

> 5. Initialize event's type attribute to `message`, […]
> 6. If the event type buffer has a value other than the empty string,
>      change the type of the newly created event to equal the value of the
>      event type buffer.

Here, you should set your listener to listen for `"foo"` events:

```
eventSource.addEventListener("foo", function() {...})
```

Comment: FYI: If you are using Spring's SSE support and are returning a SseEmitter object, the 'type' attribute seems to correspond to what you pass to SseEventBuilder.name()

Comment: Sometimes even five year old answers solve today's problems. Been banging my head against this for a few hours now. Changing server side to output event: message solved it. Many thanks.

Comment: Well, EventSource is 15 years old after all… BTW you could just omit the event type in the stream to get the same result, since "message" is the default.