# EventSource.onmessage is not firing even though Flask server push seems to work

Tags: javascript, html, flask, server-sent-events, eventsource

I created a route `/stream` which should push the string 'test' every second.

When I open this URL (`localhost:12346/stream`) on Chrome, it indeed opens a blank page and a "test" is appended to the page every second, so I think the server side is working correctly. When I opened it on Firefox, it treats it as a file download that never finishes.

But when I open `client.html` below, the `onmessage` event of the EventSource object is never fired so I get no data. The `onopen` event was fired and I see it in the console. Why is this? How can I receive the data in the JavaScript side?

server.py:

```
import flask
import flask_cors
import time

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
flask_cors.CORS(app)

def event_stream():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield 'test\n'

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    return flask.Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

app.run(port=12346, threaded=True)
```

client.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:12346/stream');
        source.onopen = e => console.log('opened', event);
        source.onerror = e => console.log('error', event);
        source.onmessage = e => console.log('onmessage', event);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Though it was later for years..
I faced the same problem with you (**message appended to the page but not fired to EventStream**)

After search so much examples & test for hours I found some key

You need to yield message with `data:` prefix and `\n` suffix, like `data:test\n\n`

So this should work for you.

```
def event_stream():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        yield 'data:test\n\n'
```

And you can see the EventStream with `Type=message, Data=test` in Chrome Debug Tools (as also `source.onmessage`)

I think it has another key word like `data:`, but I didn't find out the document about this, maybe someone can supplement.

Comment: Just was struggling for a while until I came accross this solution.

As pointed out in this answer, YOU NEED TWO NEWLINES AT THE END! A single newline does not suffice!

Answer (score 3):

[Server sent event EventStream does not trigger "onmessage" but Chrome Debug shows data in "EventStream" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971499/server-sent-event-eventstream-does-not-trigger-onmessage-but-chrome-debug-show)

That resolved my problem, backend was sending events with custom type which not triggers onmessage callback

Comment: Thanks for this! I checked Chrome Debug - it shows indeed the event stream tab because the mimetype is 'text/event-stream', but the event log remains empty (http://prntscr.com/nquvxe).

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid this problem by add @cross_origin() in your code.

```
import flask
from flask_cors import cross_origin
import time

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/stream')
@cross_origin()
def stream():
    def event_stream():
        while True:
            yield "data:" + "test" + "\n\n"
            time.sleep(1)

    return flask.Response(event_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

app.run(port=12346)
```

This is the html file

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

    var source = new EventSource('http://127.0.0.1:12346/stream');
    console.log(source)
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);        
    }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```